# Playing a chord then a note

Tags: theory, chords, chord-theory

If I played a chord (c major for example) then a note (B for example), will I hear the note B relative to C as major seventh or relative to E as perfect fifth or relative to G as major third or relative to the chord itself?

Comment: If you had taken the trouble to try this out, then you'd know what you hear.

Comment: I do a similar, but slightly different thing. To get a C note, I imagine it's the M3 of key Ab.

Answer (score 4):

> ...will I hear the note B relative to C as major seventh or relative
> to E as perfect fifth or relative to G as major third or...

Yes, one of those. Or something else.  A C chord can be followed by any other chord, including many that include the note B.  Or by no chord at all - just a note!

Play your C chord.  Then play a G chord with B in the melody.  Then try an E chord instead.  A Cmaj7 chord.  How about D6? Or B?  Or G♯dim7?

Music is all about possibilities.   There's no 'correct' chord containing B that follows a C chord.  But there's lots of choices!

Anyway, we don't know what YOU will hear.   Try!

Answer (score 3):

I think the specifics of chord voicing and inversion along with which octave you play the single `B` could effect the perception.

If the chord were root position, close voicing, `C4 E4 G4 C5` and you then played `B4` a half step under `C5` it probably has a chance of sounding like the `M7` above root `C4`.

Compare that with playing the single tone as `B3` below the `C4` which might not be convincing as a major seventh chord in third inversion. It might sound more like `C4` descending to the leading tone and a possible implied dominant harmony.

Alternately consider the chord in second inversion, open voicing, `G3 E4 C5`, and the single tone is `B4` dropped down from `C5`. That could imply a first inversion `Em` chord `G3 E4 B4`.

You will notice I'm using words like - *if*, *could*, *might*, *imply* - because only one chord and only one subsequent tone is a very limited context. My gut feeling is whatever style music you spend a lot of time playing and listening to will have a stronger effect than anything else. If that style is "classical", you're likely to hear the `B` as a leading tone or passing tone implied. If that style is modern/jazz/pop, it's more likely to sound as a `M7` over `C`.

From the traditional, classical harmonic perspective I think you want to keep in mind that major seventh chords are far less common that dominant, diminished, and minor seventh chords, and especially a `M7` above the tonic chord is just contrary to the style. Relative to a `C` major triad, the `B` is the leading tone. The leading tone's role is about making dominant harmony.

That `B` is made clear as a dominant in combination with `G` (the dominant scale degree) or `F` (the subdominant scale degree). Playing the `B` in literal isolation makes it a bit ambiguous, but part of that ambiguity is that in classical style it certainly would not sound like the `M7` of a `Cmaj7` chord, a tonic chord contrary to the style. You might say the ambiguity comes from make a muddle of the role of `B` relative to identities of tonic and dominant chords.

Try your experiment not with `B♮` but with `B♭`. With the `C` major triad in just about any inversion or voicing that `B♭` will most certainly sound as the minor seventh relative to root `C`. Part of the reason for this strong identity is there is only one diatonic dominant seventh in each key, and stylistically it is a very common chord. There will be no ambiguous muddle when you hit that lone `B♭`. It will clearly sound like a dominant chord.

From the traditional, classical harmonic perspective your experiment zeroed in on an important idea: the tonic chord is the one chord of a key that does not support a seventh or any other extension.

Comment: "You will notice I'm using words like - if, could, might, imply - because only one chord and only one subsequent tone is a very limited context": this seems the most important point. One can establish contexts to suggest any of the possibilities. The notes D-C-B-C with the words "God save the king" ("of thee I sing" in the US), only having chords with the D and two Cs, most would probably hear the unaccompanied B as a leading tone implying a G chord. But if you've got a jazzy piece full of major 7th chords, it will probably sound like a major seventh. Out of context, it's just subjective.

Answer (score 1):

If your ear hears chords as single entities then you will hear it as a maj7 to the C chord. However  it is possible for someone to hear those other relationships you mentioned. Everyone has their own unique way of hearing things.

Comment: We hope an individual isn't locked into perceiving chords and notes in just ONE way!  They should be open to many possibilities and contexts for that B after a C chord.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the notes of a chord in your head, it's easier to reference other diatonic notes from this chord. It is possible to do the other options as you say, but why would you, after hearing three main notes of the chord from a particular key?

Even if the original chord is in 1st or 2nd inversion, your ears should (with some experience), be able to add B to the C E G you hear, producing the major 7th chord. Mainly as those 3 notes should be unmistakable as C major - there's really nothing else that blend can be, making the C (wherever it is) the root. It should also work with any other notes - even, eventually with non-diatonic notes, say making C+, or C7, for example.

Working as you say, you're introducing an extra stage in the proceedings, for no good purpose. Although it's quite clever if you can.